Unbounded Holomorphic function on lines contained inside the interior of a strip
I want to find an example of a continuous function on a closed strip S and holomorphic in the interior of S in the complex plane verifying the two following properties:

$|f|$ is bounded on the boundary of S
$|f|$ is unbounded on lines contained in the interior of S

First of all I tried to work with the strip $S={{0\leq Im(z)\leq 1}}$ and I initially looked for something like $e^{z^a(z-i)^b}$ in order to get some term like xy(1-y) which would cancel on boundary plus $i\times (...)$ of norm 1 and hope for the best but it doesn't work as I always get other terms I cant get rid of for example x^3 etc without adding terms that destroy boundedness of the boundary. I also tried to map the configurazion to the unit circle but the image of a horizontal line is not soeasy to work with to find an unbounded function from unit disk so now I'm out of ideas. Anybody can help?

The example is $f(z) = \exp(-ie^{\pi z})$.
At first note that $z \rightarrow e^{\pi z}$ maps the boundary of $S$ into the real line $\mathbb R$. From this it is clear that $|f(z)| = 1$ for $z$ in boundary of $S$. Now consider a fixed $t \in (0,1)$ and a line $l = \{s + it: s \in \mathbb R\} \subset S$. Clearly, for $z = s + it \in l$ we have $$|f(z)| = \exp(\mathrm{Re}(-ie^{\pi z} )) = \exp(\mathrm{Im}(e^{\pi z})) = \exp(e^{\pi s}\sin(\pi t)).$$
Clearly, $\sin(\pi t) \ne 0$ for $t \in (0,1)$, so $|f(z)|$ is not bounded on $l$.

I see, thank you!
